# Unresolved DNS name

Tags: domain-name-system

In our company, we have two webservers, one has hostname `s1.bankklient.cz` and second `s2.bankklient.cz`.

Our application (thick client deployed to Windows OS using wininet as network connection api) which is deployed at our clients computers through country connects primarily to `s1.bankklient.cz` and when that webserver is not reachable, it connects to `s2.bankklient.cz`.

Large number of our clients (473 of total 4000) have problem reaching `s2.bankklient.cz`, as wininet returns error 12007 "Name cannot be resolved"

Our DNS server seems intact and also other DNS servers in internet can successfully resolve `s2.bankklient.cz` A record to IP address.

We are now trying to pinpoint issue cause and first thing we will try to run command `ipconfig /flushdns` at client computers.

I am concerned, that so large number of clients having the same issue. Where else could I look for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Given that both names are configured in pretty much the same way it is unexpected that it would work for one and not the other.

What you need to look for is what the clients having problems resolving the name have in common. The most obvious things to look for are:

- Are a lot of them using the same ISP?
- Are a lot of them using the same DNS server?
- Are they using a different version of OS or libraries?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can verify DNS lookups using `nslookup` without going through loops, clear cache etc.

Comment: I tried. Nslookup can not resolve hostname. I am concerned why so many clients have same problem

Comment: From here, the name server is ns1.moneta.cz (195.234.205.100 / 2001:67c:2620:406::64). By repeatedly querying it you can (somewhat) verify that it's working. If it is, the problem is a DNS server further downstream, possibly an ISP's.

Comment: Online checking tools like dnsviz and zonemaster do not find problems in the exposed zone. So your problem are probably in the DNS resolver(s) you are using.